# The property 'StatusId' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified

Tags: c#

I am using entity frame work when I tried to modify  `rm.StatusId = 3;`
 I get the title question error.
Also please give me links to know each and everything about entity frame work with asp .net controlls.

```
if (chk.Checked == true)
{
   MAtt_RequestMaster rm =
      ctx.MAtt_RequestMaster.SingleOrDefault(p => p.AutoID ==id);
   rm.StatusId = 3;
   ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: You cannot change an identity column's value.  If you want to learn more about entity frame work start by googling it.  If you have a specific problem which you cannot find the answer to, then come here and ask it.

Answer (score 0):

im not too familliar with lambda expressions, but i think you can do this:

```
 MAtt_RequestMaster rm =
  ctx.MAtt_RequestMaster.SingleOrDefault(p => p.AutoID ==id);

rm.YourStatusTable = (from x in ctx.YourStatusTable
                     where x.statusID == 3
                       select x).FirstOrDefault();

ctx.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem happens because you are referencing the same object more than once. This is not a limitation of EF, but rather a safety feature to ensure you are not inserting the same object with two different IDs.  So to achieve what you are trying to do, is simply create a new object and add the newly created object to the database.

** This issue often happens inside loops.  If you are using a while or foreach loop, make sure to have the New Created Object INSIDE the loop body.

try this:

```
MAtt_RequestMaster rm = new Matt_RequestMaster();
rm.StatusId = 3;
ctx.MAtt_RequestMasters.Attach(rm);
ctx.SaveChanges();
```